# Getting intermittent errors on Azure Media Services while creating streaming locators

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

[image]

Also getting socket exceptions at times. I haven't faced these issues until sometime back but now repeatedly getting these errors intermittently. What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you update your post and provide part of the code of creat stream locators to help you deal with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reached out to Microsoft Support. The reason for errors was that I was creating a new streaming locator for each streaming request and I was being throttled after 100 locators. Instead switching to AES encryption helped which meant there was no reason to create a new streaming locator each time.